# cant push to bitbucket forked repo

Tags: git, bitbucket

Here is my situation: I am a newbie to git and for learning purpose:

1. I (User A) created a repository in bitbucket. Then cloned the repo and created a readme file and pushed it successfully to remote.
2. I signed up as another user, lets say user B on bitbucket. As user B, I have a read access to User A's repo. I forked the repo and then cloned it. The local repository for this clone resides in the same folder as the User A's local repository.
3. As User B when I try to push my changes I am getting the error 'Authentiation Failed'.
4. I have double checked the passsword
5. I have also checked the remote url using 'git remote show origin'. The remote url looks something like https://userB@bitbucket.org/userA/testing.git.

Answer (score 0):

You can push by https but you need to include the username and password. I recommend changing to [SSH](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Use+the+SSH+protocol+with+Bitbucket).

```
git remote --set-url origin userB@bitbucket.org/userB/testing.git
```

*EDIT* I just noticed you are trying to push to someone else's repository! You can't do that unless they allow you. You should take a copy of their repository (so it is under bitbucket.org/userB/testing.git) and push your changes there - then they have the option of pulling your changes out of your repository and merging them back into their repository.

Comment: user A has given read access to user B and user B has forked this repo and is trying to push the commits to this forked repo

Comment: If userB has been granted write access to userA repo and authentications fails then surely either a) userB does not have write access to userA repo or userB has got his password wrong - neither of which is a git problem per-se.